# Ionic 3 build --prod causes white screen on iOS only

Tags: ios, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi i'm trying to compile my Ionic 3 app to iOS and it does not seams to be working.
The compilation works fine, however, when i'm trying to test the app using an iOS emulator, I got a white screen.

There is no error in the console, nor in the XCode error log.

I know the code is Ok since it's working perfeclty on android and browser.

I have tried to remove and reinstall the iOS platform, to remove and reisntall the `node_module` folder with no success.

My guess is, that the code isn't even loaded since when i'm trying to inspect the emulator using Safari Developer tool, the title of the page is index.html rather than the title i've set on the login page.

Here are the relevents files :
My config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mycompany.myAwesomeApp" version="3.0.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>my awesome app</name>
<description>My awesome app description</description>
<author email="support@myCompany.com" href="https://myCompany.com">My company dev team</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
<platform name="android">
    <!-- irrelevent android icons -->  
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
   <!-- irrelevent icon files -- >
</platform>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~2.2.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.7" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^2.0.2" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.3.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-headercolor" spec="^1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="2.0.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.1">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
<engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
<engine name="browser" spec="5.0.1" />
<engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5" />
```

Ionic Info :

```
Ionic:

    ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (/Users/nic/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/ionic)
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.0
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.4

Cordova:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
    Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
    Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 16 other plugins)

System:

     NodeJS : v10.15.3 (/Users/nic/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node)
     npm    : 6.4.1
     OS     : macOS High Sierra
     Xcode  : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255
```

Comment: There are some breaking changes in `ionic-webview` v4. Please go through the docs. I hope it'll help you.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this did not work. @AnkitKumarSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding my problem. I was loading code in the constructor rather than in an ionViewDidLoad function. I have no idea why this works on Android, but not on iOS.